# How to determine which task is running in Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, parallel-processing, google-cloud-run

I want to run [parallel tasks in Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/parallelism).

Each task does the same thing, but over 1/Nth of a dataset, and I want to run N tasks.

From my experience, when running processes in parallel, there is sometimes a way to tell what task number you're currently in, and out of how many.  This is usually done through the environment.  For example, CircleCI gives you `CIRCLE_NODE_TOTAL` and `CIRCLE_NODE_INDEX` found [here](https://circleci.com/docs/parallelism-faster-jobs/#manual-allocation).

Is there an equivalent in Google Cloud Run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they are defined as: `CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX` and `CLOUD_RUN_TASK_COUNT`, docs found [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#jobs-env-vars)